# Trying to call an API using a trigger and get data

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-api-php-client

I am very new at this and I am trying my best to work it out. It would be glad if someone can really save my day.

Trying to call an API using a trigger and get data using google scripts this is the best I came up with.

Basically I have an api which gives me objects if I putit in Postman. All I need to do it get those object in google spreadsheets.

I have tried onOpen function which was giving me an error of" You do not have permission to call Fetch".

So have been trying with on edit of first column as "Get Data" so the api can be called.

Thanks in advance

```
function onEdit(e) {


    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  if (s.getName() == "Sheet1") { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();


    //Updates timestamp for lead entry and meetings.
    var currentCellValue = r.getValue();
    var user = Session.getEffectiveUser();
    if (r.getColumn() == 1 && (currentCellValue == 'Get Data')) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 4);
      if (nextCell.getValue() == '') { //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5:30", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")).setComment(user);


        var url = "My API";
        var headers = {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Authorization": "userkey"

        };
        var options = {"method":"GET","headers": headers 
        };
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
        Logger.log(response[0]);
      }

    }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a long standing issue that still hasn't been taken care of, see [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=185)

Someone in the thread mentions

> But, using a custom function name like myOnEdit(), and connecting it
>   to the onEdit event manually, totally works!
>
> `function myOnEdit(e) {   ...   var x = fetchUrlApp.fetch(...);   ... }`

So you have to create `myOnEdit` and then put an onEdit trigger on it, either via Resources > Current Project's triggers or via the trigger service.

Comment: Had checked with a different article which works. But not on edit. Which anyways can get me the same data. Below link can help for people who are looking to get data on UrlFetch..

 https://gist.github.com/varun-raj/5350595a730a62ca1954..

Thanks Robin